# Simplifying LINQ query in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

Table1

```
Table1ID   Name  Graduation Version Hobbies  
1            A       Degree    1        B
2            A       Degree    2        C
3            A       Degree    3        D
```

Table2

```
Table2ID   Table1ID Name  Graduation  Version Address Surname    Date
1              1       A      Degree       1      A     A           08-10-2019
2              2       A      Degree       2      A     A           08-10-2019
3              3       A       Degree      3       A    A
```

//I want to check if any version greater than highest version exists in Table1 .where Date column is not null in Table2
Suppose for the combination of Name and Degree , the highest version is 2 in Table2 since Date is null for Table2, I want to check if any record greater than 2 exists in Table1, if yes add it to a new List

Here is what I am doing.

```
List<Table2> groupByTable2 = //Operations on Table2 and get highest Version record from db
List<Table1> check = new List<Table1>();
List<Table1> check2 = await _table1.GetAll().ToListAsync();
Foreach(var a in groupByTable2)
{
   List<Table1> check4 = check2.Where(x => x.Name == a.Name && x.Graduation == a.Graduation).ToList();
  If(check4.Any(x=>x.Version > a.Version))
  { 
     check.Add(check2.Where(x=>x.Table1ID == a.Table1ID).First());
  }
}
```

Now my check contains a record where ID is 3. But is there any simpler way to achieve this in simpler way with readability and performance?

Comment: "GetAll" sounds like the whole table is read from the database into memory. You can skip all the .ToList()s and have just the .Any execute in the database. More commands to execute but maybe much less data

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood what you are trying to achieve. You could try the following.

```
var result = table2.Where(x=>x.Date!=null)
                   .GroupBy(x=> new {x.Name, x.Graduation})
                   .SelectMany(x=> x.OrderByDescending(c=>c.Version).Take(1))
                   .Join(table1,t2=>t2.Table1ID,t1=>t1.Table1ID,(t2,t1)=>t1)
                   .ToList();
result.AddRange(table1.Where(x=> result.Any(c=>c.Name.Equals(x.Name) 
                                            && c.Graduation.Equals(x.Graduation) 
                                            && c.Version < x.Version)));
```

The idea is to first use `GroupBy` and Join to get the List of Items with highest `Version` number in `Table1` that has a valid date in `Table2`. Then, use `List.AddRange` to add remaining higher versions from `Table1`.